# Django Rest Framework - Why am I getting an error when the function isn't even supposed to do anything

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Have this URL:

```
path("products/product/<int:product>/rating/", ProductRating.as_view()),
```

and this view to handle the URL:

```
class ProductRating(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ProductRatingSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        breakpoint()
```

In the URL the product in int:product is just the id of the product in question. No matter what I put there whether it be int:pk or int:id I get the same error every time:

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product'
```

I have tried using generic view RetrieveAPIView and just an APIView and i get the same error. Why am I getting an error and not the breakpoint?

Comment: You have missed `self` in `get` function.

Comment: makes no difference with self I still get the same error

Comment: Now add `*args`, `**kwargs`

Comment: Try adding `product` parameter to the `get()` method signature. It would look like this: `def get(self, request, product):`. That's what the error is mentioning: another part of the program is trying to call `ProductRating.get()` with another argument called `product` and the method's signature doesn't have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get(request, request, product):
        breakpoint()
```

**it should work now !**

Comment: Is it not part of the request object? why must I add the extra argument?

Comment: i think you also can access it from the ``request.kwargs.get("product")``

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you deal with a url that have a query parameter(id, pk, slug...) in the path its going to passed to view function as kwarg. so you have either define explicit argument that captures that or u can defined a **kwargs argument in the function.

the implementation:

```
def get(self, request, product):
    ....
```

or

```
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    product = kwargs.get("product")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved with explanation:

Firstly adjust your url as following:

```
path("products/rating/<int:product>",ProductRating.as_view()),
```

It is to avoid any possible conflicts with other urls, to put the keyword at the end. Also add *args and **kwargs with your get function to pass the sent keyword to the function.From the error in extracting the product, it seems this will resolve your issue.

Below i have improvised the get function, so that you can extract the url parameter for the class based view, by using self.kwargs, and also return JsonResponse as to complete the function to return a response.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class ProductRating(APIView):
   permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
   serializer_class = ProductRatingSerializer 

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      product_id = self.kwargs["product"]
      breakpoint()
      return JsonResponse(data={"status": "200, Yay it works"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment bro. I have added explanation, and will now give better improved answers. !